# Ejs - How can we hover in ejs file?

Tags: css, angularjs, node.js, ejs

I want to implement a function. My app is made in angularjs and nodejs. I am sending an email, and in that email I have a button to click.

```
<td style="padding-top:32px;" class="suggest-artist">
                    <a href="<%=url%>" style="border:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); text-align:center; display:block; font-size:17px; text-decoration:none;
                        color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); font-family:'SlateStd-Bk', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'; padding:27px 10px 22px;"
                        onMouseOver="bgChange('green')"
                        onMouseOut="bgChange('blue')">Suggest artists now</a>
        </td>
```

I want to change the background color on hover, but it seems like it does not work this way. I googled and tried to implement inline hover but it does not work either. So I find this solution `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` but this does not work either. I also tried to include an external CSS but it does not work. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

In your inline style, you have `color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);` which overrides the ability to change hover state on your link.

You can, but you don't need JS to change color on hover. Use something like `:hover` - see below:

```css
.suggest-artist__link:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<td style="padding-top:32px;" class="suggest-artist">
                    <a href="#" class="suggest-artist__link" style="border:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); text-align:center; display:block; font-size:17px; text-decoration:none; font-family:'SlateStd-Bk', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'; padding:27px 10px 22px;">Suggest artists now</a>
        </td>
```

EDIT: Sorry - you wanted background color, not link color...do this:

```css
.suggest-artist__link:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<td style="padding-top:32px;" class="suggest-artist">
                    <a href="#" class="suggest-artist__link" style="border:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); text-align:center; display:block; font-size:17px; text-decoration:none; font-family:'SlateStd-Bk', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'; padding:27px 10px 22px;">Suggest artists now</a>
        </td>
```

Comment: it will work in normal html, but how can this work in email ?

Comment: you can try putting it in a `<style>` tag but in actual email `:hover` is not consistently supported and you can't use JS for it.